# Mathematical/statistical notation of a linear regression model with three-way interaction

Tags: regression, interaction, notation

I am unsure how to present the equation of a three way interaction linear model (without expanding all the interaction effects).

Let me clarify:

$y$ is a continuous outcome measured at time $i$ (for $i$ = 0,1,6,12 and 24 weeks).

$time$ is considered a factor/categorical variable.

$treatment$ denotes the group of exposure (1 or 0).

$smoking$ is a binary covariate

The non-statistical (incorrect, but simplified) presentation is:
$y = \text{treatment} + \text{smoking} + \text{time} + \text{treatment} \times \text{smoking} + \text{treatment} \times \text{time} + \text{smoking} \times \text{time} + \text{treatment} \times \text{smoking} \times \text{time}$

A more statistical notation is:

$y_{ijk} = \beta_0 + \beta_{\text{treatment}}\text{treatment}_{ijk} + \beta_{\text{smoking}}\text{smoking}_{ijk} + \beta_{\text{time}}\text{time}_{ijk} + \beta_{\text{treatment}\times\text{smoking}}\text{treatment}_{ijk}\times\text{smoking}_{ijk} + \beta_{\text{treatment}\times\text{time}}\text{treatment}_{ijk}\times\text{time}_{ijk} + \beta_{\text{smoking}\times\text{time}}\text{smoking}_{ijk}\times\text{time}_{ijk} + \beta_{\text{treatment}\times\text{smoking}\times\text{time}}\text{treatment}_{ijk}\times\text{smoking}_{ijk}\times\text{time}_{ijk} +\epsilon_{ijk}$

where $i$ denotes the group, $j$ denotes the time category and $k$ denotes the smoking category.

However, it is still incomplete.

Any references or suggestions indicating a better notation (statistically complete and concise)? Perhaps using a matrix notation?

Comment: TBH I am not sure what you are going for here. A linear model only requires that it is linear in its parameters, leaving many things to be specified for an actual model. These parameters could be assumed to be constants in the population, or they could be functions, or they are themselves random variables or even stochastic processes. And then there are there distributional assumptions. And assumptions about where the error terms occur (it doesn't always have to be additive)... There seems like a lot of heterogenous choices that together don't admit to a unique choice of notation.

Comment: Thank you, Galen. Very insightful thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix notation is $Y = XB + \epsilon$ for any linear regression model.

But be careful! I don't think you want a linear regression model here. The error terms aren't independent. You probably want a multilevel model.

Comment: Than you, Peter. The challenge is that time has several dummies.

Comment: @Jacob Can you clarify why dummy variables are a problem? Typically they are included as variables in the matrix $X$ in Peter's post.

Comment: Dummy variables are, as @Galen said, not a problem for matrix notation.

Whether time should be categorical is another matter.

Comment: @PeterFlom I have been thinking about this issue of using time as a categorical variable in time course experiments. It seems to me that it leaves information on the table b/c time is totally ordered (for a local observer in spacetime). I've developed a model structure, a special case of multilevel models, that I call *cumulative mixed effects*. It is pretty much what it sounds like; you nest the effects such that they accumulate the time points in the desired order. This seems to be a better option for including some information about order.

Comment: @Galen Sounds fascinating.  I'm pretty much retired (I do some article reviewing) so I wouldn't be using it, but I might recommend it if you develop it or publish it. Keep me posted.